# How can I work on a same java workspace with different pcs?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have to work on the same code and folders on different computers (one at work and possibly more than one at home).
 All what I need is a simple way to:

- have three (or more) folders (one on each computer and one on the usb pen drive) all synchronised with each other
- deal with them using eclipse only (no git, if possible, or, at most, an elementary use of it)
- handle the whole workspace (source, libraries, other note files, ...).
  I have already found similar questions but I still don't get from the answers what can be easily done to get the result.

Comment: Think what you Need is a Version controll System like git

Comment: Could you suggest me any simple tutorial for the use I need?

Comment: Look at http://github.com

Comment: Things such as path to your JVM is not portable from a machine to another, so you cannot share a full workspace and expect it to work. However, you can share all the <project>/.classpath <project>/.project <project>/.settings/ ... that should be portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: if you have to **manage** versions of source code; no matter if one system or multiple - then better use a **source management tool** for that. That could be git (because everybody is using that nowadays; so you find a lot of information about it), or any other system. [ hint: alone the fact that you are talking about **multiple** machines makes it even more important to look into appropriate tooling ]

It might feel inconvenient to learn about such tooling; as you just want to do "development"; but seriously: managing your source code is an **essential** part of professional software development. You can't just detour that part without consequences.

One alternative could be to look into products like [Eclipse Che](http://www.eclipse.org/che/) which provides a "cloud based" work space.

Long story short: don't waste your time on half-baked, quarter-robust, zero-stable workarounds. Better spent some hours more on getting git, svn, whatever up and running. It will soon pay out. And don't get yourself fooled. These things aren't "simple". They require some serious time if you have not dealt with it before. Really, look into books like [pro git](https://progit.org/) to understand what you are about to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Git program to **version** your work folder: [Git](https://git-scm.com/)

After that, you could put it in remote and share it with your team or anyone using some mainstream platforms like [GitHub](https://github.com/) or [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)

I suggest you to watch out for some simple Git commands like:

```
git init
git add
git commit
git push
git pull
git clone
```

Very usefull are too:

```
git checkout
git merge
```